# Java split function

Tags: java, split

Hi I have a question about java split

```
ItemName,Item,,(width,length,height),12
```

I want String[] equals this"

```
String[] result ={"ItemName","Item","","(width,length,height)","12"};
```

Who can help me with using split function or other regex?

Answer (score -1):

If your input string is named *istr*, then

```
 String[] result = istr.split(",");
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
String data="ItemName,Item,,(width,length,height),12";
        String[] result=data.split("//,");
        for(String string : result) {

            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

Comment: If you vote me down at least tell me why or do not do it please